# Bounding probability of picking point from $l^p$ ball

Tags: probability, geometric-probability

> Consider picking $x$ randomly and uniformly from the $l^p$ ball with radius $R$, $B_p^d(R)$. If $0\le \gamma \lt 1$, how can I conclude following?
>   $$
>     P(\| x\|_p \le \gamma R)
>   = \frac{\operatorname{Vol}(B_p^d(\gamma R))}{\operatorname{Vol}(B_p^d(R))}
> $$

Comment: This depends greatly on how you pick this point randomly. A great example to illustrate this is Bertrand's paradox https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability).

Comment: You can get displayed equations by surrounding them with double instead of single dollar signs; that makes them easier to read, especially when you're mixing fractions, subscripts and superscripts. You can also get proper norm bars by using `\|` instead of `||`. Here's [a tutorial and reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: @joriki I edited my question. Thank you

Comment: I forgot to mention that you can get the proper font for operators like $\operatorname{Vol}$ using `\operatorname{Vol}`; I've edited the question.